# Using Ajax Inside CJUIDialog

Tags: php, yii

I have a CJUIDialog where i load the content of another form using renderPartial. In that form there is an ajax button where it loads another form. That form contains another ajax button where i need to load the previous form inside the dialog itself. I have tried doing it like this. But it doesnt work.
In my controller i have two methods that prints out the two forms like this.

```
public function actionNewRecipients(){
        $customer = new Customer;
        $address = new Address;
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_form_new',array('customer'=>$customer,'address'=>$address,'guest'=>true),true);

        echo $content;
}
public function actionAddRecipients()
{ $content = $this->renderPartial('_form_inner',array(),true);

    echo $content;}
```

And then in one form i have the ajax button like,

```
            echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('New','New Recipient'),CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('customer/newRecipients')),array('success'=>'js: function(data) {
                    alert("new");
                    $("#dialog_gift").html(data);

                    $("#dialog_gift").dialog("option","title","Select Recipient");


                }'));
```

and in the other form i have the ajax button like,

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('New','New Recipient'),CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('customer/addRecipients')),array('success'=>'js: function(data) {
                    alert("select");
                    $("#dialog_gift").html(data);

                    $("#dialog_gift").dialog("option","title","Select Recipient");
                    //$("customer-form_inner").attr("action","'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('customer/newRecipients')).'")

                }'));
```

And the CJUIDialog looks like,

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
'id'=>'dialog_gift',
// additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>$title,
    'autoOpen'=>false,
    'modal'=>true,
    'scrolling'=>'no',
    'resizable'=>false,
    'scrollable'=>false,
    'closeOnEscape' => true,
    ),
));
echo '<div class="span-24">';
echo $content;
echo '</div>';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

Ill be initially loading one forms content.

The first transition happens properly. But after i replace the html content the second transition to load the other view does not happen.

Please let me know if anyone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the 4th parameter of the `renderPartial(string $view, array $data=NULL, boolean $return=false, boolean $processOutput=false)`-function. By setting `$processOutput` to true, all necessary scripts (including those to enable ajax-button-functionality) will be included and executed.

Comment: i set the fourth parameter to true in both of the methods.. then the problem is it executes over and over again... without having to click on the ajax submit button at all...

Comment: okay, sorry that it didn't work out. Would you mind to copy all of the important parts of your code (the both forms, both controller actions) to, e.g., [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so we can take a closer look at it and find out where the error is located?